# MVC EF select multiple joins

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, select

I have the following DB structure.
[image]

I want to make a select using Entity Framework. I want all my `Categories` that MAY have a `CategoryText`. If They have a `CategoryText` I also need to get the `Language`.

I searched and I couldn't find anything useful.
Here is my query that doesn't work:

```
var categoriesSQL = db.Categories
                   .Include(i => i.CategoryTexts.Select(s => s.Language)
                   .Where(w => w.Format == (string)Session["chosen_language"]));
var categories = categoriesSQL.ToList();
```

It throws: 
`The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.
Parameter name: path`

I tried to solve this in a lot of ways and recomandations but I couldn't find a solution.

I want the select made in only one query.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var language = (string)Session["chosen_language"];
var categoriesSQL = db.Categories
                   .Include(i => i.CategoryTexts.Select(s => s.Language))
                   .Where(c => 
                          (from ct in c.CategoryTexts
                          from l in ct.Languages
                          select l.Format).Contains(language)
                    );
var categories = categoriesSQL.ToList();
```

OR

```
var language = (string)Session["chosen_language"];
var categoriesSQL = db.Categories
                   .Include(i => i.CategoryTexts.Select(s => s.Language))
                   .Where(c => c.CategoryText
                                 .Any(ct => ct.Languages
                                      .Any(l => l.Format == language)
                                 ) 
                    );
var categories = categoriesSQL.ToList();
```